# PHP joined tables display repeats

Tags: php, mysql

I joined two tables successfully but I can't figure out how to condition a variable that repeats.

```
$kelo = "SELECT e.id, e.rosary, e.group_name, e.description, u.group_id, u.name, u.decade, u.intention, u.datume FROM `rosary_group_name` AS e INNER JOIN `rosary_groups` AS u ON e.id = u.group_id ORDER BY e.id DESC, u.group_id DESC;";

    $melo = mysqli_query($con,$kelo);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($melo)){
        echo '<div style="clear:left;">' .$row['rosary']. " - ". $row['name'].'</div>';
        echo "<br />";
    }
```

Display is :

```
JOJO - hello1
JOJO - hello2
JOJO - hello3
PAJO - hi1
PAJO - hi2
KAJO - Cheers1
KAJO - Cheers2
KAJO - Cheers3
```

but I need:

```
    JOJO - hello1
           hello2
           hello3
    PAJO - hi1
           hi2
    KAJO - Cheers1
           Cheers2
           Cheers3
```

how do I achieve that?

Comment: check in your while loop the name and output the name only then, when it's value has changed.

Comment: well, I know that but the question is how to do it, lol

Comment: Did you grasp my approach in the implementation of @Stefan ;-)

Comment: yeah, but I will need to apply it to all elements from the first table. It will be a long script...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
$melo = mysqli_query($con,$kelo);
$current = '';
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($melo)){
    if($current != $row['rosary']) { 
        $current = $row['rosary']; 
        $display = $current . ' - '; 
    }
    else $display = '';

    echo '<div style="clear:left;"><span>' .$display . '</span><span>'.$row['name'].'</span></div>';
    echo "<br />";
}
```

You can use CSS to align it or sprintf if you use a plain format.

Comment: No that won't work. Your first idea with $current was the right one. Check $current and update it, if the name changes. Build $display as now.

Comment: Thank you @VMai for paying attention.

Comment: this is actually not correct, because if instead of KAJO heading is PAJO again, it will get hidden.

Comment: @Grasper do you mean in case of the 'rosary' is not sorted?

Comment: I'm not sure what u mean.

Comment: I am sorry, I can't follow what you mean.. You talk about the alignment or that the rosary-name comes back multiple times?

Answer (score 0):

If your primary focus is on e.rosary then this query may help you:

```
$kelo = "SELECT e.id, e.rosary, e.group_name, e.description, u.group_id, u.name, u.decade, u.intention, u.datume FROM `rosary_group_name` AS e INNER JOIN `rosary_groups` AS u ON e.id = u.group_id ORDER BY e.rosary ASC, e.id DESC, u.group_id DESC;";
```

Comment: JOJO - hello1
       hello2
       hello3
KAJO - Cheers1
       Cheers2
       Cheers3
PAJO - hi1
       hi2
This may be expected if you use @Stefan 's code above, while ordering first by e.rosary field

Comment: there is still a problem if for example PAJO goes after PAJO, the second PAJO won't get displayed...

Comment: @Gasper is it a problem with the query result? Please post the result of the SQL query I mentioned above. We must identify where the problem occurs