# MySql limiting only first table from joined table

Tags: php, mysql

I'm kind of struggling to limit only one table from the joined table.

I want to limit only the first table rosary_group_name. In the code below I limit both tables. Any idea?

```
$sql = "
    SELECT e.id,
           e.rosary,
           e.group_name,
           e.description,
           u.group_id,
           u.name,
           u.decade,
           u.intention,
           u.datume 
      FROM `rosary_group_name` AS e 
INNER JOIN `rosary_groups` AS u 
        ON e.id = u.group_id 
  ORDER BY e.id DESC $limit;
";
```

the variable $limit sets the number of rows to display from both tables. I want to apply $limit only to the first table.

Comment: What does "limit only the first table mean".  Consider editing your question and adding sample data and desired results.

Comment: this is for pagination, so I'd like to select the number of rows only from the first table, does this make sence?

Comment: It does not as the data u select comes from 2 tables, hence the join

Comment: the variable $limit sets the number of rows to display from both tables. I want to apply $limit only to the first table.

Comment: Please edit post with sample data and expected result

Comment: You know that you are in effect ordering by the same column twice, right?

Comment: @DarkBee, sample data are here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24918055/php-joined-tables-display-repeats

Comment: @Grasper Your phrasing "limit only one table" does not make sense. An SQL query's results are represented as rows of data. When you JOIN, either a LEFT, RIGHT, or INNER, you are (potentially) adding **columns** of data to each row. The joined table does not create new *rows*, but new *columns*. So, how can one only limit the rows selected from one table in a join? You need to explain your goal a little better, as it stands, this is un-answerable because it is illogical.

Comment: I already checked the correct answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use a sub-query for the first table, like

```
SELECT 
       e.*
       u.group_id,
       u.name,
       u.decade,
       u.intention,
       u.datume 
FROM (SELECT e.id, e.rosary, e.group_name, e.description, FROM `rosary_group_name` AS e $limit) AS e 
INNER JOIN `rosary_groups` AS u 
        ON e.id = u.group_id 
ORDER BY e.id DESC;
```

(not sure if the syntax is correct, sorry. but I hope you get an idea)

Comment: I already figured it out but still I will give you points, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Inner join will give you limited(matched rows) result. You should consider left join in order to get more result from the left side table